# Verify if reCaptcha v3 in Nuxt is working properly

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, recaptcha

I'm installing [@nuxtjs/recaptcha](https://github.com/nuxt-community/recaptcha-module) on my nuxt project, which is google reCaptcha V3. It looks like it's working great it's always returning `success` result from the servers like below.

```js
{success: true, challenge_ts: '2022-05-05T11:37:06Z', hostname: 'localhost', score: 0.9}
```

But I'm not sure this work properly because the challenge does not appear. Recaptcha as I know it, should have a challenge that must be met. But why doesn't the challenge appear here?

Maybe it needs to be triggered with some event handler? But in the documentation example I didn't saw any things related about it or maybe I just do not realize it.
May be im missing something important, so I need your help to figure it out.

My template code

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 align="center">SEND EMAIL TO US!</h1>

    <div class="layout">
      <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
        <div class="basic-info">
          <div class="name">
            <label for="">Name :</label>
            <b-form-input v-model="data.name" placeholder="Name"></b-form-input>

            <div v-if="validation.name" class="mt-2">
              <b-alert show variant="danger">{{ validation.name[0] }}</b-alert>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="email">
            <label for="">Email :</label>
            <b-form-input
              v-model="data.email"
              placeholder="Email"
            ></b-form-input>
            <div v-if="validation.email" class="mt-2">
              <b-alert show variant="danger">{{ validation.email[0] }}</b-alert>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="messege">
            <label for="">Messege :</label>
            <b-form-textarea
              id="textarea"
              v-model="data.messege"
              placeholder="Enter Messege..."
              rows="8"
              max-rows="8"
            ></b-form-textarea>
            <div v-if="validation.messege" class="mt-2">
              <b-alert show variant="danger">
                {{ validation.messege[0] }}
              </b-alert>
            </div>
          </div>

          <hr />
          <b-button type="submit" variant="outline-primary">
            SEND EMAIL
          </b-button>
          <hr />
          <b-alert v-model="alert" show :variant="variant">
            {{ result_messege }}
          </b-alert>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

my script code

```html
<script>
export default {
  async mounted() {
    try {
      await this.$recaptcha.init()
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async onSubmit() {
      try {
        this.loading = true

        // Start the verification process
        const response = await this.verifyCaptcha()

        console.log(response)

        // Display error message if verification was not successful
        if (!response.success) {
          this.$recaptcha.reset()
          this.loading = false
          this.errorStatus = true
          this.notificationMessage =
            'There was an error with your reCaptcha verification. Please try again.'
          return
        }

        // If verification was successful, send the message
        await this.sendMail()

        this.errorStatus = false
        this.notificationMessage =
          'Thank you for reaching out. We will get back to you as soon as possible'

        this.loading = false
        this.$recaptcha.reset()
      } catch (error) {
        this.loading = false
        console.log(error)
      }
    },

    async verifyCaptcha() {
      try {
        const token = await this.$recaptcha.execute()
        console.log(token)

        const response = await this.$axios.$post(
          `/captcha-api/siteverify?secret=${process.env.SECRET_KEY}&response=${token}`
        )

        return response
      } catch (error) {
        this.loading = false
        return error
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally normal, this is the whole concept of the v3 as you can see in this video: https://youtu.be/tbvxFW4UJdU

More details are also here: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3
And here: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/about/

So far, the feature is exactly this: do not require any interaction from the user but rather use some mouse trackers/AI to know if it's potentially malicious or not.

Comment: thanks bro , is there a way to test the captcha to make sure it works fine?

Comment: @shinichirouikebe you can check [the score](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3) mainly, try to pass the page you have a validations with different mouse moves/keyboard shortcuts or alike and see how it changes. Also, setting a score lower/higher is important regarding the security. The documentation is quite well made regarding this. Otherwise, if it works well and passes, you have nothing to really worry about. :)